# Bidirectionnal Sync with shell/terminal and actual code in Codenvy

Tags: shell, docker, synchronization, codenvy, web-ide

I managed to create a [working shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USZYG.png) with the following runner:

```
FROM codenvy/shellinabox
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install g++ git htop ssh tmux vim python
VOLUME ["/home/user/app"]
ENV CODENVY_APP_BIND_DIR /home/user/app
CMD sleep 365d
```

This will sync changes from the [Codenvy WebIDE](http://imgur.com/6TiNT24) to the [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwDaO.png).

But it won't [sync changes from the terminal to the Codenvy WebIDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3hub.png)(even if you attempt to refresh,close/open file, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I work for Codenvy...

Bi-directional sync between the runtime and project files in the IDE is part of the next-generation Codenvy system which is now in beta. The only way to do it with the Codenvy version currently hosted at codenvy.com is to implement an [extension for Codenvy](http://codenvy.readme.io/docs/developing-extensions) that checks with a process in the runtime for changes.

It would be easier to use the next generation system where this just works out-of-the-box - you can play with it by signing up for the beta at [codenvy.com](https://codenvy.com/product/getting-started/) or (since Codenvy is based on the Eclipse Che open source project) you can [download the 4.x version of Che](https://eclipse.org/che/download/) and use it on your laptop.